# IOS not displaying alternative colours in coregraphics

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-graphics

Here I am not getting alternative colors on the UIView using core graphics.
I would like to understand core graphics drawing.

```
    class ProgressMenuView: UIView {

    var colors : [UIColor] = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green,UIColor.red,UIColor.green]
    var values : [CGFloat] = [50, 100, 150, 180]

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        var cumulativeValue:CGFloat = 0

        for i in 0..<self.values.count {
            ctx!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: cumulativeValue, width:100, height: values[i]))
            ctx!.setFillColor(colors[i].cgColor)
            cumulativeValue += values[i]
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is a little error in your code. These lines should probably be reversed:

```
ctx!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: cumulativeValue, width:100, height: values[i])) // ...then fill
ctx!.setFillColor(colors[i].cgColor) // you should first set the color...
```

We just need to look at what each variable's value is at the start of each iteration of the for loop.

- 1st iteration

  - `cumulativeValue` - 0
  - `values[i]` - 50
  - `colors[i]` - red
  - so this iteration fills the rect (0, 0, 100, 50) with red
- 2nd iteration

  - `cumulativeValue` - 50
  - `values[i]` - 100
  - `colors[i]` - green
  - so this iteration fills the rect (0, 50, 100, 100) with green
- 3rd iteration

  - `cumulativeValue` - 150
  - `values[i]` - 150
  - `colors[i]` - red
  - so this iteration fills the rect (0, 150, 100, 150) with red
- 4th iteration

  - `cumulativeValue` - 300
  - `values[i]` - 180
  - `colors[i]` - green
  - so this iteration fills the rect (0, 300, 100, 180) with green

I recommend drawing these rects on a piece of paper and colouring them in with the colors. You will see how this works.

To explain briefly, each element of `values` stores the length of each "segment" of the view. There are 4 segments, each longer than the previous one. And `cumulativeValue` stores the y value of where the next segment should be drawn.

Here's how it looks in a playground:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the fill color before calling `fill()`. When I do that it draws the colors in your colors `Array` as expected.